# What happens to a cosine when sending it through a LTI system?

Tags: laplace-transform, signal-processing

> What happens to a cosine when sending it through a LTI system?

This question came up in my last signal processing class. The professor elegantly answered that it simply gets scaled and shifted. I tried to verify this at home but the result didn't confirm what he said:

The input-signal is defined as $x(t)=cos(\omega t)$. Furthermore it can be shown that the output of a LTI-system is calculated by $ y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(t-\tau)h(\tau)d\tau$.

\begin{align*}
y(t)&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} cos(\omega(t-\tau))h(\tau)d\tau\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (\frac{1}{2}e^{-i\omega (t-\tau)}+\frac{1}{2}e^{i\omega (t-\tau)})h(\tau)d\tau\\
&=\frac{1}{2}e^{-i\omega t}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{i\omega \tau}h(\tau)d\tau + \frac{1}{2}e^{i\omega t}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-i\omega \tau}h(\tau)d\tau\\
&=\frac{1}{2}e^{-i\omega t}H(-j\omega)+\frac{1}{2}e^{i\omega t}H(j\omega)
\end{align*}

But a scaled and shifted cosine would actually look like this:
$$
a*cos(t+b)=\frac{1}{2}ae^{-ib-it}+\frac{1}{2}ae^{ib+it}
$$

Is my professors statement right? Did I make a mistake in my calculations / is my aprroach wrong?

Comment: Your professor is correct.  You seem to be having some trouble recognizing that $y(t)$ you've calculuated is a phase shifted/amplified cosine.  You'll want to take advantage of a special property of the Fourier transform of a real impulse $h(t)$.  You'll also have to convert back from complex exponential to sin/cos form.

Comment: You extracted the wrong time-variable from the convolution integral. The factor $e^{i\omega\tau}$ must remain in the integrand but you can extract $e^{i\omega t}$. If you take this into account you end up with a scaled and shifted cosine as output signal.

Comment: Also note $H(i\omega) = |H(i\omega)| e^{i\Im(log(H(i\omega)))}$ and $H(-i\omega) = H(i\omega)^* = |H(i\omega)| e^{-i\Im(log(H(i\omega)))}$. Don't know wether I should also remaind you that $\omega$ is a fixed parameter in this calculation -- it is **not** a variable. So, all terms in the preceeding calculation can be evaluated to complex numbers. There are no fancy variables in there!

Comment: @Tobias Could you explain why there is $log(H(i\omega ))$ in the exponent? I think I understand where it leads to (getting $i\omega \tau $ down), but there is also the integral and impulse response.

Comment: $z = e^{\log(z)} = e^{\Re(\log(z))+i\Im(\log(z))} = e^{\Re(\log(z))}\cdot e^{i\Im(\log(z))} = |z| \cdot e^{i\Im(\log(z))}$. There is no $i\omega\tau$ involved with $\log(H(i\omega))$. Best is you set $a:=|H(i\omega)|$ and $b:=\Im(\log(H(i\omega)))$. As I already tried to tell you: There are no fancy variables involved in these two parameter expressions $a$ and $b$. Since $\omega$ and $H(\bullet)$ are given $a$ and $b$ can be evaluated to complex numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Tobias. Another question related to this came to my mind: Since the cosine is simply stretched and time shifted when going through the system, but the actual function stays the same, are those values which determine the stretch and shift eigenvalues of the system? The definition of eigenvalues/eigensignals says $y(t)=H(x(t))=\lambda x(t)$, where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue and $x(t)$ an eigensignal. So there is actually no time shift in there. (Should this question be added into my original question?)

Comment: $t\mapsto e^{i\omega t}$ is an eigenfunction if it is in the domain of $H$. One of the premises is that $H$ is defined for complex time-signals. If $H$ is defined by its impulse-response $h$, the Fourier-transform of $h$ must exist. That depends on interpretation. If the Fourier-transform should exist in $L^2$ then $h$ must be in $L^1$.